Upwork GraphQL API - Freelancer Feedback
I cannot for the life of me figure out how to see my feedback on contracts via GraphQL.
Can someone please help me with this? I'm developing internally and have full access/permissions on this key I am using.
Here's what I have currently:
 `      query GetContractFeedback($contractId: ID!) {
contract(id: $contractId) {
id
title
feedback {
 clientFeedback {
comment
 }
    }
}
}

{
"errors": [
    {
        "message": "The client or authentication token doesn't have enough oauth2 permissions/scopes to access: [ClientFeedback.comment, Feedback.clientFeedback]. For more information check: https://www.upwork.com/developer/documentation/graphql/api/docs/index.html#getting-started-application-permissions document link",
        "extensions": {
            "classification": "ExecutionAborted"
        }
      }
     ]
     }`


Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
